# Regex lookbehind in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am having an issue with lookbehind in java. 
The following method

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String num = "1E-12x10";
    String[] numArr = num.split("(?<!E)\\-");
    System.out.println(numArr[0]);

}
```

produces the output 1E-12x10 as expected - it does not split on the '-'.

The following method

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String num = "1E-12x10";
    String[] numArr = num.split("[x\\-]");
    System.out.println(numArr[0] + " " + numArr[1] + " " + numArr[2]);

}
```

also produces the expected output 1E 12 10, splitting on both 'x' and '-'.

But when I try the following method

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String num = "1E-12x10";
    String[] numArr = num.split("[x(?<!E)\\-]");
    System.out.println(numArr[0] + " " + numArr[1] + " " + numArr[2]);

}
```

I expect the string to split on 'x' but not on '-'. However, what happens is that it splits on 'x', 'E' and '-'. I am not quite sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't place lookbehinds *inside* a character class. You need to use an alternation, like this:

```
String[] numArr = num.split("x|(?<!E)-");
```

This will split the string on any `x` character, or any `-` not preceded by an `E` character. Also note that in this case the `\\` is not necessary before the `-`.

Comment: Awesome, that was quick! Thanks.